# An inequality involves sum of products of consecutive numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, factorial

> Does the following inequality hold for all $N\geq2$?
> \begin{equation*}\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}i\cdot(N-i-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{N-i}\prod_{j=k}^{k+i}j}{N(N-1)N!}<1.\end{equation*}

I have tried some numerical examples. It seems they all checked out.

If so, a proof (or any hint) will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Say $N=5$. The numerator takes the form \begin{equation*}1\cdot 3!(1*2+2*3+3*4+4*5)+2\cdot 2! (1*2*3+2*3*4+3*4*5)+3\cdot 1!(1*2*3*4+2*3*4*5)+4\cdot 0! (1*2*3*4*5)=1512,\end{equation*}while the denominator takes the value $5*4*120=2400$. I have tried to prove it by induction with no luck.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\prod_{j=k}^{k+i}j=\frac{(i+k)!}{(k-1)!}=\binom{i+k}{i+1}(i+1)!$$

Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{k=1}^{N-i}\prod_{j=k}^{k+i}j&=(i+1)!\sum_{k=1}^{N-i}\binom{i+k}{i+1}\\
&=(i+1)!\binom{i+N-i+1}{i+2} \qquad\text{(by the hockey stick inequality)}\\
&=(i+1)!\binom{N+1}{i+2}=\frac{(N+1)!}{(N-i-1)!\cdot(i+2)},
\end{split}
$$
so
$$
i\cdot(N-i-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{N-i}\prod_{j=k}^{k+i}j=\frac{i}{i+2}(N+1)!=\left(1-\frac{2}{i+2}\right)(N+1)!
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}i\cdot(N-i-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{N-i}\prod_{j=k}^{k+i}j&=(N+1)!\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}\left(1-\frac{2}{i+2}\right)
\\&=(N+1)!\left(N-1-2\sum_{i=3}^{N+1}\frac{1}{i}\right)\\
&=(N+1)!\left(N-1-2\left(H_{N+1}-1-\frac{1}{2}\right)\right)\\
&=(N+1)!(N+2-2H_{N+1}),
\end{split}
$$
where $H_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}$ is the $n$th harmonic number.

Finally,
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N-1}i\cdot(N-i-1)!\sum_{k=1}^{N-i}\prod_{j=k}^{k+i}j}{N(N-1)N!}&=\frac{(N+1)!(N+2-2H_{N+1})}{N(N-1)N!}\\
&=\frac{(N+1)(N+2-2H_{N+1})}{N(N-1)}.
\end{split}
$$

So, your question can be restated as follows:

> Is $\displaystyle\frac{(N+1)(N+2-2H_{N+1})}{N(N-1)}<1$ for all $N\ge 2$?

The equivalent bound on $H_{N+1}$ for $N\ge 2$ would be
$$
2(N+1)H_{N+1}>(N+1)(N+2)-N(N-1)=4N+2,
$$
i.e.
$$
H_{N+1}>\frac{2N+1}{N+1}=2-\frac{1}{N+1},
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
H_n>\frac{2n-1}{n}=2-\frac{1}{n}
$$
for $n\ge 3$.

And indeed, for $n\ge 3$,
$$
H_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{i}=1+\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{1}{i}>1+\sum_{i=2}^{n}\frac{1}{n}=1+\frac{n-1}{n}=\frac{2n-1}{n},
$$
which proves the original inequality.